# WP_Query with OR conditions

Tags: php, wordpress

Here is an issue, I have a site that has sort of complex search. I have set several arguments: `s`, `meta_query`, `tax_query` and `post_type`

Obviously these are all linked with `AND` relationships (except `meta_query` and `tax_query` that can be set with `OR` relationship, but I need to get posts that have entered phrase at either title or content or some of meta values, or some of taxonomies.

Any way of doing so?

Answer (score 0):

You should use [relation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) parameter.

**UPDATE:**

Example from a page linked above:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'movie_genre',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => array( 'action', 'comedy' ),
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'actor',
            'field'    => 'term_id',
            'terms'    => array( 103, 115, 206 ),
            'operator' => 'NOT IN',
        ),
    ),
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Come on, this is WP codex. If it will change this would be for a good reason. So in this particular case "link only" answer is more valid as it will never rot. In any way I added code example.

Comment: True, that link will never rot, but good content can be replaced with crap. Take the child theme page. The current page is wrong, the way how the stylesheets are loaded is **wrong**. The current method loads the child stylesheet twice. I have fixed that twice to avoid this problem and even done a post on WPSE about that, but one ignorant person keeps changing my changes back to this crap version :-)